# liquibase - Is it possible to compare data of databases with liquibase?

Tags: java, database, liquibase

I am new to liquibase, and when I looked in the documentation, I found only how to compare database schema not data.
If it is not possible, is there any other JAVA API that will help in comparing data and supports multiple vendors of relational databases?

Comment: what is database (vendor, version).  there are many tools for specific databases.

Comment: @Jayan I want to compare relational databases, it could be Mysql, postgres, oracle...